# get all markers from database in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, servlets

I have a Google Map where i have shown markers  to indicate some places these places have latitude,longitude and names now i want to show get those information from database.I am using mysql. this is i have done so far..

this is my servlet portion where i am creating a jsonObject from database with lat long and place name.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    DbConnectionDaoImpl dbConnectionDaoImpl = new DbConnectionDaoImpl();
    Connection con = dbConnectionDaoImpl.dbConnect();
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * from mapTable ";
    System.out.println("Test Query" + sqlQuery);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
    ArrayList<MapInfo> markerList;
    markerList = new ArrayList<MapInfo>();

    while (rs.next()) {

        MapInfo marker = new MapInfo(); //model class with attributes latitude,longitude and name along with their getters and setters
        marker.setLatitude(rs.getString("latitude"));
        marker.setLongitude(rs.getString("longitude"));
        marker.setPlace(rs.getString("place"));
        markerList.add(marker);

    }
    String JsonString = gson.toJson(markerList, ArrayList.class);
    out.print(JsonString);
```

and this my jsp portion  where i have to show the google map from database...

```
 <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></div>

    <script>
        var jsonString = 
            document.getElementById("map").value;//which includes  lat and long values as json object. 

            var markersJson = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString); 
        for (var i = 0; i < markersJson.length; i++) { 
            var latLng = new 
            google.maps.LatLng(markersJson[i].lat, 
            markersJson[i].lng); 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: 
                    latLng, clickable: true, icon: 
                    markersJson[i].iconPath, map:map }); 
        } 
    </script>
```

This is my code where all the information are shown.
i want to call this JsonString object in my jsp page
Somebody please help